# Is it possible to show/hide a Callout when pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have a `MapView` where I show multiple locations via `Marker`s, and an array of `TouchableOpacity`s that act like buttons.

Every time one of those buttons is pressed, the user will be directed to a specific marker on the map. Also, for each `Marker`, I have a Callout with a custom component that shows the info of that location.

My question is, how can I show/hide the Callout when I press the `TouchableOpacity`? When I press on the Marker directly, the Callout shows. That's what more or less what I'm trying to archieve.

My code of the Map looks like this

```
<MapView.Animated
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  initialRegion={initialRegionMap}
  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
  showsUserLocation
  region={region}
>
   {
     events.map((event, index) => (
       <Marker
         key={index.toString()}
         coordinate={event.eventLocation}
         pinColor={event.isPrivateEvent ? theme.colors.Gold : theme.colors.Red}
       >
         <Callout tooltip onPress={() => goToEvent(index, event.eventName, event)}>
           <EventMapCard
             eventNameText={event.eventName}
             dateText={event.eventDayStart}
             hourText={event.eventHourStart}
             organizerNameText={event.organizerName}
             organizerImageSource={event.organizerImg}
             isPrivateEvent={event.isPrivateEvent}
             imageSource={event.imageLink}
           />
         </Callout>
       </Marker>
     ))
   }
</MapView.Animated>
```

And the code of the buttons goes like this

```
<FlatList
  data={events}
  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
  style={{ marginTop: 20, marginHorizontal: 15 }}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Block>
      <EventCardSmall
        eventNameText={item.eventName}
        imageSource={item.imageLink}
        dateText={item.eventDayStart}
        hourText={item.eventHourStart}
        organizerImageSource={item.organizerImg}
        onPress={() => updateRegion(item.eventLocation)}
      />
    </Block>
  )}
/>
```

I tried to do it using `useState`, but it doesn't work at all.